# php getcwd() - exclude server directories

Tags: php, explode, getcwd

I have the following line of code which works on my local machine because the root directory of the server is the same as the root directory of the site.

```
$directories = explode("/", str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/", "",  getcwd()));
```

How can I adapt this to work on my remove server where the root directory is several levels below that of the site. I guess I need to only include the site directories rather than the server directories.

Answer (score 0):

My logic states you need to put your remote server address here:

```
$directories = explode("/here/", str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/", "",  getcwd()));
```

If that doesn't work, 
check these threads out, I think your solution is in one of them

SO Thread:
[Root path doesn't work with php include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400795/root-path-doesnt-work-with-php-include)

Tech-Recipes-Thread:
[PHP: determine the directory path of the server root](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/313/php-determine-the-directory-path-of-the-server-root/)